# Question about proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading the book Advanced Calculus by Edwards, H. M. (1980), and I came across the following proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus, which is given as below.

[image]
[image]

I do not understand the following parts of the proof.

1. It says that the expression (12) "can be thought of as the average difference per unit length between...".
   What does it mean by "the average difference per unit length"?
   I understand that the "per unit length" part comes from $\frac{1}{\Delta t}$ in (12), what about the "average difference" part?
2. How does $|\epsilon_{ab}| \geq \frac{1}{2}(|\epsilon_{ac}|+|\epsilon_{cb}|)$ imply that $|\epsilon_{ac}| \geq |\epsilon_{ab}|$ or $|\epsilon_{ac}| \geq |\epsilon_{ab}|$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The difference between the integral and the other expression, taken over the whole interval from $a$ to $b$, is $$\left[\int_a^b F'(t)\,dt\right]-\Delta F(t)$$ If we divide by the length of the interval $\Delta t=b-a$, then we get the total difference per length, or the average of the difference over the interval. For instance, a difference of $10$ over an interval of length $5$ is an average difference of $2$ per unit length.
2. Suppose that both $|\epsilon_{ac}|<|\epsilon_{ab}|$ and $|\epsilon_{cb}|<|\epsilon_{ab}|$. Then $${1\over 2}\left(|\epsilon_{ac}|+|\epsilon_{cb}|\right)<{1\over 2}\left(|\epsilon_{ab}|+|\epsilon_{ab}|\right)=|\epsilon_{ab}|$$ a contradiction, as the two are equal.

---

I should add that the wording of the proof is a bit misleading. The proof does *not* in fact analyze the errors over each of the sub-intervals into which $[a,b]$ is partitioned to take the Riemann Sum. Instead, it only analyzes *one* error - namely, that between the integral and the expression that the integral is claimed to equal - and shows that this one error is less than a quantity which tends to zero.

Comment: That helps alot. I was confused with the word "average" as I thought that the word "per length" already implies some sort of "average". By the way, do you mind explaining to me the part where it says "if the interval is further subdividied, then the maximum of this average, like any average, can only increase; that is, the average on at least one of the smaller invervals is as large as the average over the whole interval"? What does it mean by "like any avearge"?

Comment: @user144840 Basically, if you have a function with an average of $5$ over an interval, and you split it into two intervals, either the average over both sub-intervals is still $5$, or one average went up and the other went down (by the same amount) - e.g., it might now be $4$ on one half and $6$ on the other half. Hence the max between the two intervals is greater than or equal to the original average.

Comment: I have some perplexity on the passage $$\lim _{\Delta t \rightarrow 0}\frac 1{\Delta t} \int F'(t)\,dt-\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac {\Delta F}{\Delta t}=F'(T)-F'(T)=0$$Don't you ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo The first integral divided by $\Delta t$ gives the average value of $F'$ over an interval whose length is shrinking to $0$ - they reference part (v) of chapter $2.6$, so I'm assuming that was proved earlier in his/her textbook.

Comment: I cannot understand why Edwards uses the _average_ difference and not the difference (he says this is helpful). What do you think ?